# Overwrite current line with register?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

I often want to copy a line and replace another line with the pasted copy. Is there a better way than `Y` on source line, go to the line that has to be replaced and `Pjdd`?

Comment: `pkdd` ? (It's one keypress less for the `Shift`)

Comment: that would be `pkdd` :)

Comment: What did you say? :p

Comment: That's "register", not "buffer".

Answer (score 5):

You can go to the source line, yank it with `yy` or `Y`, go back to the target line, and press `Vp` (select the line with a visual selection, and replace the visual selection with the previously yanked line).

Comment: For me, `Y` also yanks the whole line. Is this nonstandard? I usually prefer `Y` over `yy`. There is a difference however between `D` and `dd`.

Comment: @Jasper Oh, sorry, answering from mobile and don't have an actual Vim instance to test. Edited.

Comment: @Jasper `Y` and `yy` are synonymous...per `:h Y`